# XMLHTTPrequest not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am making a request to a service in 2 ways

1) Through XMLHTTPRequest->Not Working

says --> JSON.parse unexpected end of data in line1 col1

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

function sign() {          
  var logincredentials = JSON.stringify({
   "username": "_username",
   "password": "_passsword"
  });

  var url = serviceurl; 
  var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
  }

  xhr.onload = function () {
    alert("success : ");
  };

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    alert("failed : ");
  };            
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jsonrequest; charset=UTF-8');
  xhr.send(logincredentials);
}
```

[image]

2) JQuery Ajax working Fine

```
function signJQ() {
  var userData = JSON.stringify({
    "username": "_username",
    "password": "_password"
  });

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"serviceurl",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data:userData,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("Failed: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
}
```

What might be the difference in both the cases?

Comment: Did you define `createCORSRequest` function ?

Comment: It is defined here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: which browser did you try?

Comment: By xhr there is `onreadystatechange` only as far as I know. So use that instead of `onload` and `onerror`. Ohh I was wrong, [xhr2](http://caniuse.com/xhr2) works with both onload and onerror.

Comment: Can u try this: `xhr.send("json="+logincredentials);`

Comment: The code seems to be ok. :S Are you sure that this code causes the problem? Do you have an error message?

Comment: Error Message : JSON.parse unexpected end of data in line1 col1          Even I tried xhr.send("json="+logincredentials); but No luck

Comment: What is the raw data sent back by the server? This does not make sense, you don't parse any JSON in your code...

Comment: I am cant see the response.. It says Syntax error in response

Comment: Yes, but with firebug net panel you should be able to see the raw response body. And if there is any error in the console, that too..

Comment: Yes I see, but that is not firebug net panel, it is the firefox console, or something similar. In firebug I always see the raw data as response. Btw I think you should look around on server side, because I think there is nothing wrong with the request. The response is invalid, not the request...

Comment: http://s29.postimg.org/453p4z5iv/N_vtelen.png

Comment: Btw there should not be JSON auto parse (according to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/)), not even by XHR2, and since you don't parse the response, the error message does not make any sense. Maybe JSONRequest works otherwise. Does it work with the `application/json` content type? If yes, then it is something jsonrequest related.

Comment: "`The only accept type used with JSONRequest is application/jsonrequest. `" - http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html I am not sure that this rule is forced by the browser, but if yes, then probably this causes the problem... I am not sure, that jsonrequest is a built-in browser feature or just a library you can load in. I think you should forget that mime type if it is just a library.

Comment: Hmm. `unexpected end` can probably cause by CORS, because it does not allow reading response from another domain if the CORS headers are not properly set. Another possibility that the content-length is not properly set. I have no other guesses. :S What are your CORS headers on the server?

Comment: but it works with Jquery Ajax

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jsonrequest; charset=UTF-8');
```

should certainly be:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: not really, `application/jsonrequest` is a correct mime type

Comment: No, it really isn't a correct mime type.  Please show where this mime type is defined in the spec: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Comment: Ohh I see, you are right. It was [defined here](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html) by Crockford, but it was never registered. He registered [application/json](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) instead. Anyways I don't think it counts by solving this question, but who knows...

Answer (score 0):

Append parameters with url, "?username=_username&password=_passsword"

```
function sign() {          

            var logincredentials = "?username=_username&password=_passsword";


            var url = serviceurl; 

            var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url + logincredentials );
            if (!xhr) {
                alert('CORS not supported');
            }

            xhr.onload = function () {
                alert("success : ");

            };

            xhr.onerror = function () {
                alert("failed : ");

            };          
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jsonrequest; charset=UTF-8');
            xhr.send();

        }
```

also you need the function [createCORSRequest()](http://pastebin.com/0LT35xcL)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet that has been given below may it works in your case:

> function createXMLHTTPObject() {
>
> ```
> var xmlhttp = false;
> for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
>     try {
>         xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
>     }
>     catch (e) {
>         continue;
>     }
>     break;
> }
> return xmlhttp;
> ```
>
> }

And Work with request :

> function createCORSRequest(method,url) {
>    var xhr = createXMLHTTPObject();
>
> ```
>  xhr.open(method, url,true);
>  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
>  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
>  xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
> {
>      if (xhr.readyState)
>      {
>          if(xhr.status==200){
>              request.success(xhr.responseText);
>          }else if(xhr.status!=200){
>              request.error(xhr.responseText)
>          }
>      }
>  }
>  xhr.send(body);
> ```
>
> }